# Saving and restoring an observableArray containing nested observableArrays

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a model which I need to save to JSON and re-load as required. The idea is that the user can save the model to a basket or database (as a JSON string) and then reload it. It's simple enough to create the JSON and save it but re-loading is seemingly much more difficult. The problem is that my model includes some complex objects similar to the Knockout Contacts example:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

I can even generate the JSON and pass it via a web service into an .NET object.

I've looked at the Knockout documentation for loading a data model:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

...and I can easily restore my "simple" observables but I don't see how I can initialise my arrays of complex objects where these objects also contain observable arrays. Any ideas?

I've even tried using the mapping plugin but the resulting JSON doesn't contain the information in the arrays.

Doing this creates the JSON and all my data is in there:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2)
```

Ideally, I just need to reverse this or at least create all the objects one by one.

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 0):

The mapping plugin *should* work. I'm not sure if i understood correctly your situation, but try somethig like that:

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.contacts = ko.observableArray();
}

var model = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);

var json = '{"contacts":[{"name":"Tom","phones":["00000000","1111111111"]},{"name":"Bill","phones":["222222222","333333333"]},{"name":"Bert","phones":["444444444","55555555"]}]}';

ko.mapping.fromJSON(json, {}, model);
```

The observableArray of "contacts" and "phones" in each contact are deserialized correctly from the json string.

http://jsfiddle.net/k4Sth/1/

Comment: OK, that looks interesting - I'll try that out tomorrow and report back. Thanks for the quick reply :)